# Кастомизация RadioButton в C#

Tags: c#, .net, наследование

Всем привет

При загрузке контента, мне нужно привязать некоторый объект к radiobutton'у, поэтому принял решение создать класс-наследник от класса RadioButton и при его инициализации, в конструкторе передавать ему необходимый объект.

Всё хорошо, написал что-то вроде этого:

```
class CustomRadioButton : RadioButton
    {
        private object _object;

        public CustomRadioButton(object obj):base(){
            _object = obj;
            /*
              необходимая обработка объекта
             */
        }
}
```

Вроде всё нормально, но этот кастомный radiobutton просто не отображается.
Создаю элемент как по учебнику:

```
CustomRadioButton radioButton = new CustomRadioButton(obj);
```

И добавляю его на форму, тоже, как по учебнику:

```
parentElement.Controls.Add(radioButton);
```

Думаю, я что-то упустил и возможно нужно переписать метод OnPaint или что-то подобное, но вопрос к вам, аноны:

Что я делаю не так?

Comment: А вы его добавили на форму?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, конечно. Забыл дописать в вопросе.

Comment: В этом коде ошибок нет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Окей, проблема решена.

Дело в том, что во время обработки объекта я устанавливал параметр Anchor. А как вы знаете, при создании элемента у него нет ещё родительского элемента, поэтому после установки:

```
this.Anchor = (AnchorStyles.Left | AnchorStyles.Right);
```

У элемента схлопывалась ширина до нуля. Поэтому его было не видно.

Всем спасибо!